# How to retrieve the current counter value using Opentelemetry Java API?

Tags: java, counter, open-telemetry

As per my understanding OpenTelemetry is designed to capture incremental changes and is primarily used for aggregating and exporting metrics to monitoring systems. However, it does not provide a direct means to access the current value.

I'm trying to bridge between our custom Counter API and opentelemetry-java API. I'm able to do the increment or decrement but unable able to identify how to retrieve the value of the counter.

Is there any way to retrieve the current counter value without relying on the exporter or backend system where the metrics are sent?

Comment: "Is there any way to retrieve the current counter value without relying on the exporter or backend system where the metrics are sent?" - No. In OpenTelemetry metrics, the API is strictly for recording measurements. Access to the aggregated metrics is only available through the SDK by registering a custom reader / exporter.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way would be to use an asynchronous counter, where you store the value yourself, and provide a callback to OpenTelemetry to access that value using [buildWithCallback](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/blob/main/api/all/src/main/java/io/opentelemetry/api/metrics/LongCounterBuilder.java#L61).

Comment: Argh! This is exactly the thing I wanted to avoid where we end up storing the counter value on our end too. We thought of this but were hoping there might be a better way to do this. I like the idea of not exposing the value in the API as mentioned in the OTEL specification, but unfortunately, we have legacy instrumentation API that still needs to be supported and bridged with opentelemetry-java API

Comment: As an alternative, you could use the micrometer metrics api (which allows you to get the current value), which can export to OpenTelemetry.